# slicing in 2d vector cpp

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to create a new row in my 2d vector with the elements from index 1 to the end of the previous row. I wrote the below code but it is wrong. Can you please help me.

```
   vector<vector<int>> res;
   k=res.size();
   res.push_back(res[k-1].begin()+1,res[k-1].end());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `vector::push_back` you append an element from value_type of the vector, and you can't push_back a range

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

You should call `std::vector` constructor in order to construct the new row, and push it to your vector:

```
res.push_back(vector(res[k-1].begin()+1,res[k-1].end()));
```

You can also call the constructor implicitly by using `{}`, but implicit constructors might make your code harder to maintain.

```
res.push_back({res[k-1].begin()+1,res[k-1].end()});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only missing a `{}`:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> res{{1,2,3,4,5}};
   auto k=res.size();
   res.push_back({res[k-1].begin()+1,res[k-1].end()});
}
```

`push_back` takes an element of the container that you need to construct, and that is a `std::vector<int>`. Alternatively you can call `emplace_back` wich does work with parameters for the elements constructor:

```
res.emplace_back(res[k-1].begin()+1,res[k-1].end());
```